# jQuery UI : How can I fetch data from an array on drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let suppose I have an array

```
<script>

    sectionsP = {
        "test": {
            "sections": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "test1",
                    "html": "<div id='test1-id'>Test 1 Hello</div>"
                }
                "2": {
                    "name": "test2",
                    "html": "<div id='test2-id'>Test 2 Hello</div>"
                }
            }
        }

        "dummy": {
            "sections": {
                "1": {
                    "name": "dummy1"
                    "html": "<div id='dummy1-id'>Dummy 1 Hello</div>" 
                }
                "2": {
                    "name": "dummy2"
                    "html": "<div id='dummy2-id'>Dummy 2 Hello</div>" 
                }
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

I want know that how can I featch the data on drop event. For example If I have drag n drop test 2 so I want that the array from test -> sections -> 2 value in dropped in html format.

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/82/)

Updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MyTests/pL4Lv6r9/83/)

Comment: What have you been trying so far? In your fiddle there is no JSON and the dragging and dropping does not work...

Comment: @Cossintan I am just making thing for my own practice I am a newbee in js not very new but more that 7 months and sorry for JSON its the typo mistrake

Comment: May I suggest using CSS3 animations instead of `.slideDown();` since CSS3 animations are hardware accelerated :)

Comment: @Cossintan if you have any idea that how can I do that so please help.

Comment: @XanderLuciano Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @user7791702 link(https://jsfiddle.net/zLjgmvx2/1/)